# Detect if recycler view items fit the screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a chat activity inside it there is a recycler view that display chat message items.

I am confused in deciding the stack orientation of the recycler view, I want the items to show directly from bottom when activity launches, so I do this:

```
     linear_layout_manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

(linear_layout_manager) is the layout manager of my recycler view .

**The problem**

If I do as I mentioned above then I face a problem when I send the very first message. In which it starts stacking from bottom leaving the above of the recycler view empty.

**Why do I need to use stack from end?**

you may ask me why not scroll to bottom on activity launch, I will answer you that if I do so then user can visualize the recycler view scrolling to bottom.

But I need to instantly show the last item on activity launch.

**My thought**

I think that this thought can help, but not sure if it works:

```
     if(/*items are all fit to screen*/){
         linear_layout_manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
       }else{
         linear_layout_manager.setStackFromEnd(false);
        }
```

Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm not sure if you're still dealing with this issue since it's been a while, but recently I ran into a similar situation and this is how I dealt with it. Hope it can help others than ran into this problem in the future.

Firstly I assume that you're using reverse layout here.

The key is to do this inside an `OnLayoutChangeListener` so as you grow / shrink the number of items inside the list `setStackFromEnd()` can be adjusted dynamically.

You can also do a `notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end to force a re-layout of the recycler view.

```java
recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener((view, left, top, right, bottom, oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom) -> {
 boolean isPageFilledWithItems = 
     recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange() > recyclerView.getHeight();

 ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).setStackFromEnd(!isPageFilledWithItems);
});
```